# Mediator file in silverlight mvvm applications

Tags: silverlight, mvvm, eventaggregator, mediator

In silverlight-MVVM applications, we have to use some kind of mediator/even aggregator file..to commuunicate between different viewmodels.

But I can see that these files maintains list(or dictionary) of objects ...

wont this be using huge amount of memory...? And in case of a web pplication (if it is WPF, that is okay)...is this something recommended ?

Any help would be appreciated. 
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.  Remember it is not making copies of the objects, just pointers to them.  However, some implementations of this pattern can cause memory leaks if you do not unregister your objects when you are done with them.

Comment: We have a list of objects maintained in this class..then isnt it a copy ?. Could you give me an example of code that yo mean, please

Comment: List<object> is not a list of objects.  It is a list of pointers to objects.  This is how .NET works.